# Replace value from text in href attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change the value of expand to 0 when the DOM is ready.

I've tried different things

```
$('.link-comment').attr('href').find("expand=1").replaceWith('expand=0');
```

But it's not working. So I can I change the value of expand to 0

```
<a class="link-comment" href="/eventcomments/create-like/227?expand=1">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
$(function(){
    $('.link-comment').attr('href', function (_, cur) {
        return cur.replace(/expand=1/, "expand=0");
    });
});
```

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ThDK/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.link-comment').filter('[href*="expand=1]"').attr('href', function(idx, href){
    return href.replace('expand=1', 'expand=0')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.link-comment').attr('href',$('.link-comment').attr('href').replace("expand=1", "expand=0"));
```